# Why does N25Q512 has 0x20 for capacity ID?

Tags: identification, flash

Command 0x9F is expected to return three bytes - manufacturer ID, and two bytes of ID[15:0] with LSB being capacity ID. I am building catalogue of the serial flash chips basing on [this excellent header file](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/third_party/flashrom/+/master/flashchips.h), and see the following:

```
....
db  0bah,019h,"N25Q256",0
db  0bah,020h,"N25Q512",0
....
```

Till today I thought that if I take capacity ID of the serial flash device I can reliably know its size. Now I am stuck:

[N25Q256](https://www.micron.com/~/media/documents/products/data-sheet/nor-flash/serial-nor/n25q/n25q_256mb_1_8v.pdf) - capacity ID 0x19 - 2^25 * 8 = 256Mb

[N25Q512](https://www.micron.com/~/media/Documents/Products/Data%20Sheet/NOR%20Flash/Serial%20NOR/N25Q/n25q_512mb_1ce_3v_65nm.pdf) - capacity ID 0x20 - 2^32 * 8 = 32Gb ???

While for N25Q512 datasheet says "512Mb, Multiple I/O Serial Flash Memory".

And it seems not to be a mistake in the doc - as I read over the internet that device really reads 0x20.

Why they did not set capacity ID as 0x1A? Stacked device IDs start with 0x20? Any knowledge or legitimate guess?

Comment: This looks like a mistake to me. Someone was thinking "oh, it's double the previous one, that means 19+1 so 20", forgetting that it's not in decimal.

Comment: I though this way too, until found that people report flash really reads 0x20.

Comment: That might be good to include in the question, then. I've got nothing, if that's not the problem.